# Can this be turned into dom xss?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

I am testing a bug bounty website and i reached a support ticket creation functionality. I registered with email address `{{15*15}}@testemail.com`.
I created a ticket but when i try to open the ticket i noticed a call to `https://www.website.com/undefined` and i am not able to open the ticket, it keep saying "loading ticket" but it never loads. I believe that this error is caused by {{15*15}} that is injected in some javascript file and generate that error. I tried to register with emails like `"></script><xss>@email.com` or `alert(1)@gmail.com` but the email in registration page is controlled and doesn't let me register with invalid emails. Can i execute some javascript code or exploit this issue as dom based xss? If possible what payload could i insert inside email field?

Comment: Is email validation done client-side? Also, I highly recommend looking into blind XSS and tools such as XSSHunter: https://xsshunter.com/.

Comment: @EdOverflow,
I think their support ticket system is made by zendesk but the problem here is with one of their script. I think this is the code generating the error 

`{var i=this.users[o];t.author_id===i.id&&(t.author_nickname=i.name,t.author_avatar=i.email===this.user.email?this.user.avatar:i.photo.content_url?`

The problem is that email is validated server side and it block regular brackets `()` while curly brackets are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share errors written at console ?

This type of contents does not send to browser over js files, I believe you can find it in a response of document request or initial response. Most of the time you can find it at html response or API response (json/xml etc.).

If you want to check XSS, follow items listed below.

- Find the input at response (alert(1)@gmail.com
- Check, is app do html encoding/decoding (write <> and check response is <> or <>)
- If it does not handle correctly, find the right payload

You are working with stored XSS so you can follow this link https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Stored_Cross_site_scripting_(OTG-INPVAL-002)

You can find out example payloads at link written below
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

PS. This situations can be a simple frontend error so check the reason first (reason of "loading tickets").

Comment: In console i have the following errors:

`pid-user-file-min.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'content_url' of null
    at e.getUsers (pid-user-file.js:1)
[...]
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()   undefined:1`

Comment: I believe no because most of the time at that step you need to see a syntax error.
Second scenario: your payload is not injected properly this why it will not giving syntax error, you can try bypass registration page for injecting html tags (<script>alert();</script>).

For being sure you can follow items listed at previous message.

Comment: Did you get that the payload is injected in `email` input?  < and > are blocked, also normal brackets are blocked.

Comment: Yeap got it.. I am talking about evading your payload, please have a look to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.
Also, if this "invalid mail" validation done at frontend (JS) you need to send this data directly to backend and check what is happening.